# Menu bar dictionary search

Tags: menu-bar, dictionary

Is there an app that allows me to search the mac dictionary from the menu bar? I thought spotlight was able to do this but it doesn't seem to work (in Lion) (I noticed Dictionary isn't even listed in spotlight preferences).

I (stupidly) forgot to mention that I forbade spotlight from indexing my main drive. I thought that would just keep it from searching my files and not affect dictionary search, but I'm guessing that they're all bundled up together.

Comment: The answer of @dave-delong gives as good solution but as today it is not possible to change a order of sections in spotlight search. So, I am also interested in an app which will give me a possibility to search from top menu bar directly.

Answer (score 1):

Spotlight *can* do this.  You just need to hover your mouse over the "Look Up" entry:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Spotlight is able to search in you dictionary. Just make sure it is selected in System Prefernces -> Spotlight